# List categories year by year in wordpress mu

Tags: wordpress, templates, plugins, wp-list-categories

We have installed a multi-WP for a school. They have a need to display the list ordering, year by year, the categories used that year. For example:

- Issues of 2014

  - Category 3 < link to the posts in 2014 under "Category 3"
  - Category 5
  - Category 20
- Issues of 2013

  - Category 3
  - Category 10
  - Category 7
- Etc

They could tell me the code to implement this in a template or plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Although this will output categories (each post will have its category with it) a bit different from the format that you have mentioned above, but this will get you started:

```
<?php
// get years that have posts
$years = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT YEAR(post_date) AS year FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type =   'post' AND post_status = 'publish' GROUP BY year DESC" ); //assuming that you have default wordpress table prefix

foreach ( $years as $year ) {
// get posts for each year
$posts_this_year = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT post_title FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type = 'post' AND post_status = 'publish' AND YEAR(post_date) = '" . $year->year . "'" ); //assuming that you have default wordpress table prefix

echo '<p>Issues of ' . $year->year . '</p><ul>';
foreach ( $posts_this_year as $post ) {
    $category = get_the_category( $post );
    $post_url = get_permalink( $post->ID);
    echo '<li>' $category[0]->cat_name.' | '. '<a href="'.$post_url.'">'.$post->post_title . '</a></li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
}
?>
```